# Как отследить ошибку из-за которой падает Google Chrome

Tags: jquery, google-chrome, javascript

Добрый день! Есть туристический сайт с формой поиска городов и автокомплитом. При выборе города из выпадающего списка срабатывает небольшая js функция:

```
    var write = function(value){
        $value.val(value[0]).trigger("change");
        $input.val(value[1]);
        $country.text(value[2]);
        console.log("write to html");
    };
```

она считывает значения грода и страны из выпадающего списка и распихивает их по переменным (перемнные определены ранее при загрузке формы). Всё прекрасно работает, однако, если делать выбор города многократно (т.е. понажимать мышкой по выпадающему списку городов) гугл хром выкидывает такую ошибку http://joxi.ru/DBA0Xd8uZdQAy9 . Версия гугл хром 37.0....и что-то там. Версия старая, в текущей стабильно 38-й ошибки нет, но 37-й пользуются ещё многие.

Как можно отследить ошибку? Может быть сторонняя консоль какая-нибудь или что-то такое есть?

P.S. Срабатывает именно функция write т.к. я понатыкал по всем js функциям console.log("что запускается").

P.P.S. В консоли хрома ошибки не выскакивет, просто идёт сообщение о вызове функции write (write to html), правда дважды т.к. она проверяет оба поля (откуда, куад).

P.P.P.S. В chrome://crashes/ тоже ничего полезного нет, есть только идентификаторы ошибки и предложение написать разработчикам.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вобщем ответили из службы поддержки Google Chrome, сказали "...не можем повторить подобный баг в новой 38-й версии браузера, обновитесь и попробуйте ещё раз". А я точно знаю что его там нет, вобщем начальство успокоилось, обновили хром и вопрос отпал сам собой ))

Answer (score 0):

Есть же старый как мир и до безобразия надёжный способ: убирать по одной строке, пока ошибка не уйдёт. Таким образом локализовать, а дальше, глядишь, и понятно станет.